# How do you determine the drag and drop location in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I have mocked up a simple example of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

A ViewController contains 4 "drop zone" UIImageViews (e.g. **dropZone1**).  A 5th UIImageView (**playerCard**) can be dragged and dropped onto any of the drop zones, but nowhere else.

I cannot figure out the way to determine which of the 4 drop zones is where the user has dragged and dropped the **playerCard**.

My thought was to set some sort of variable in *dropInteraction canHandle* and then use that in *dropInteraction performDrop* to take the appropriate action. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: One approach is to add a drop interaction to each zone. The zone can signal back to your game logic via delegate protocol or closure. I.e “hey logic , card was just dropped on zone 2, deal with it”

Comment: I am not familiar enough with Swift to know how it is possible to add a drop interaction to each zone (UIImageView).  Every example I found only has a single drop_interaction for the entire viewcontroller and thus affects everything on it.  Can you provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: Find a tutorial, it’s a wide topic that’s not in scope for this question. SO isn’t a code writing service. E.g https://www.raywenderlich.com/3121851-drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-ios . Come back with a more focused question if you still can’t figure out what to do.

Comment: I am a raywenderlich subscriber.  Unfortunately having reviewed that already in detail, I did not find it addressed what I was needing. So as a last resort I posted something here.  My very first question. You have ensured I won't ask another question in the future.

Comment: You are correct that the tutorial that I pointed you to isn’t appropriate for your question. It deals with collection drag/drop instead. I apologise. But if you know how to add one `UIDropInteraction`  to a view then you know how to add 4 , 1 per image view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
let imageViewWidth: CGFloat = 100
let imageViewHeight: CGFloat = 200
let inset: CGFloat = 40

var arrayDropZones = [DropZoneCard]()

var initialFrame: CGRect {
    get {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.width - imageViewWidth,
                           y: bounds.height - imageViewHeight,
                           width: imageViewWidth,
                           height: imageViewHeight
        )
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addDropZones()
    addNewCard()
}
}

extension ViewController {
func addDropZones() {
    let dropZone1 = getDropZoneCard()
    dropZone1.frame = CGRect(x: inset, y: inset, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)

    let dropZone2 = getDropZoneCard()
    let x = bounds.width - imageViewWidth - inset
    dropZone2.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: inset, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)

    let dropZone3 = getDropZoneCard()
    let y = inset + imageViewHeight + inset
    dropZone3.frame = CGRect(x: inset, y: y, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)

    let dropZone4 = getDropZoneCard()
    dropZone4.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)


    [dropZone1, dropZone2, dropZone3, dropZone4].forEach {
        view.addSubview($0)
        self.arrayDropZones.append($0)
    }
}

func getNewCard() -> UIImageView {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.backgroundColor = .green

    imageView.frame = initialFrame

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:(#selector(handleGesture(_:))))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    return imageView
}

func getDropZoneCard() -> DropZoneCard {
    let dropZone = DropZoneCard()
    dropZone.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    dropZone.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return dropZone
}

func addNewCard() {
    let imageView = getNewCard()
    view.addSubview(imageView)
}

@objc func handleGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {

        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)

        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            let point = view.center
            for dropZone in arrayDropZones {
                if dropZone.frame.contains(point) {
                    dropZone.append(card: view)
                    addNewCard()
                    return
                }
            }

            view.frame = initialFrame
        }
    }

    recognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
}
}

class DropZoneCard: UIImageView {
private(set) var arrayCards = [UIView]()

func append(card: UIView) {
    arrayCards.append(card)
    card.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    card.frame = frame
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey for the that comprehensive example!  You are awesome!

Comment: This is very clean & straightforward code. Thank you